# android value adding app

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a app by which a user can register and login in the app . Now i am thinking to add value in my app . 
[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76R23.jpg)

Look at  the picture i want to add this in my profile activity . when ever a user click on the value 1 this datat will be saved in the database . and that data will string and replace 0 to 1 . after that if any user click the 5 button . +5 will add in the data base  and it will replace 1 to 6 . i want to create it for every user.

My Propile Activity

```
    package com.helploger.www.ezzeearn;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    //firebase auth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    //view objects
    private TextView textViewUserEmail;
    private Button buttonLogout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        //Toolbar

        toolbar =(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout =(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);



        //initializing firebase authentication object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //if the user is not logged in
        //that means current user will return null
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            //closing this activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //initializing views
        textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
        buttonLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);

        //displaying logged in user name
        textViewUserEmail.setText("Welcome "+user.getEmail());

        //adding listener to button
        buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //if logout is pressed
        if(view == buttonLogout){
            //logging out the user
            firebaseAuth.signOut();
            //closing activity
            finish();
            //starting login activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

//
Please help me . Thank You Guys

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and what kind of data storage are we talking about?

Comment: i want to put some button . and button values is 5 and 1 . when any user press button 5 it will save in the database after that if the same user press 1 thn +1 will save in the database and total number will be 6 . check my ss.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
Button plusOne,plusFive;
plusOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlusOne);
plusFive = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlusFive);

plusOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int reputation = getUserReputationFromYourDatabase(userId); //do the procedure to get user reputation from db
            reputation+=1;
            updateUserReputation(userId,reputation) //do the procedure to update user reputation on the db
        }
    });


plusFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int reputation = getUserReputationFromYourDatabase(userId); //do the procedure to get user reputation from db
            reputation+=5;
            updateUserReputation(userId,reputation) //do the procedure to update user reputation on the db
        }
    });
```

Write the above methods in your onCreate() method

Comment: i didn't get u .. would u please write the full code? I am using firebase database. so what is getUserReputationFromYourDatabase ???

Comment: i meant assuming that you are manipulating user reputation meaning--> when a user clicks +1 the user's reputation will increase by 1 and when user clicks +5 the user's reputation  increases by 5. so before adding a reputation to user's previous reputation first you have to get how much reputation they have from the database. then you add the amount either 1 or 5 to it and update the database again. I just used reputation as an example. u can use anything you want

Comment: no .. You dinn't understand what i say . let me explain.

Comment: i want a point database for every user. Like when a user create a account from by app a database will be create . The user point will be 0 . when that user press plus5 button the poin will be 5 . if the user again click the plus 5 button the point will be 10. i am using firebase.  do u get me?

Comment: that's what exactly i am saying. use `point` instead of `reputation` on my code.

Comment: ok . thanks . Would u pls write the code again? and i want to create different database for every user. But u didnot use any firebase database reff .